# Google Sheets: Send email when a certain value is exceeded in one cell - Problem: number in a text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automatically send an email when a certain value in one cell in Google Sheets is larger than x. The problem is: The cells I am referring to are not only numbers, but numbers in a text. The mail should be sent when the number exceeds 3.000.000,00€ (sometimes also written as "3000000 €", "3000000,00€", "3.000.000 €" etc.).

What I've got so far:

```
function FetchValue() {
      // Fetch the current value
      var CurrentValueRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Quelle_Datawrapper").getRange("D2:D"); 
      var CurrentValue = CurrentValueRange.getValue();
        // Check current value
      if (CurrentValue > 3000000,00){
        // Fetch the email address
        var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt3").getRange("B1");
        var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
      
        // Send Alert Email.
        var message = 'In Kürze steht ein Objekt zum Preis von ' + CurrentValue + ' Euro zur Versteigerung.'; // Second column
        var subject = 'Zwangsversteigerung - Objekt für mehr als drei Millionen Euro';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress.toString(), subject, message);
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is that the cell value is not recognized as a number value. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem? I was thinking of adapting the code to a certain amount of digits before ",00€" starting with a number >=3, but I'm unsure whether that's the smartest idea and/or how to write it in AppsScript...

Comment: See what the `CurrentValue` is with `Logger.log( typeof CurrentValue )`.  If its a `number` then it is just currency formatting for display.  If its a `string` then we can try to work from there.

Comment: If my understanding of `The cells I am referring to are not only numbers, but numbers in a text.` is correct, in your situation, both number and text are used. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the detail of `etc` of `3.000.000,00€ (sometimes also written as "3000000 €", "3000000,00€", "3.000.000 €" etc.)`? I thought that in this case, when all patterns are known, it will help thinking of the modification points. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cell values are `string` rather than formatted currency try this.  In my Sheet1 column A I have the 4 values you show in your question, 3.000.000,00€, "3000000 €", "3000000,00€", "3.000.000 €".  I'm not sure about your decimal, whether it is a period or comma.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.forEach( value => {
        if( typeof value[0] === "string" ) {
          value[0] = value[0].replace(/[\.€]/g,"");  // eliminate all periods & €
          let parts = value[0].split(",");
          if( parts[1] ) parts[0] = parts[0]+"."+parts[1];
          console.log("string: "+parts[0])
          let num = parseFloat(parts[0]);
          console.log("number: "+num)
        }
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
7:01:38 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:01:39 AM  Info    string: 3000000.00
7:01:39 AM  Info    number: 3000000
7:01:39 AM  Info    string: 3000000.00
7:01:39 AM  Info    number: 3000000
7:01:39 AM  Info    string: 3000000 
7:01:39 AM  Info    number: 3000000
7:01:39 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```